# How to proceed tasks under executor thread?

Tags: java, android, threadpoolexecutor

I am using executor to access RoomDatabase and it seems that nothing happen under these background tasks. For example for the creation of a entity in my database (here called Note):

**NoteDataRepository Class**

```
package com.example.grimoire.data.repositories;

...
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class NoteDataRepository {

    private final NoteDao noteDao;
    private final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    private final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    Note note;


    public NoteDataRepository(Context context) {

        GrimoireDatabase db = GrimoireDatabase.getInstance(context);
        this.noteDao = db.noteDao();
        this.allNotes = getAllNotes();
    }


    //=== Create Note ===//
    public long createNote(){
        Note note = new Note();
        Log.i("NoteDataRepository:createNote", "newNoteId before executor : " + note.getId());
        executor.execute(() -> {
            Log.i("NoteDataRepository:createNote", "newNoteId in executor : " + note.getId());
            noteDao.insertNote(note);});
        Log.i("NoteDataRepository:createNote", "newNoteId after executor : " + note.getId());
        return note.getId();};

    //...

}
```

When I call the `createNote()` method from the NoteDataRepository class I get this Logcat :

```
2023-09-26 12:22:46.737 10805-10805 NoteDataRe...createNote com.example.grimoire                 I  newNoteId before executor : 0
2023-09-26 12:22:46.738 10805-10805 NoteDataRe...createNote com.example.grimoire                 I  newNoteId after executor : 0
2023-09-26 12:22:46.739 10805-10805 NoteViewMo...createNote com.example.grimoire                 I  newNoteId : 0
2023-09-26 12:22:46.742 10805-10805 AndroidRuntime          com.example.grimoire                 D  Shutting down VM
2023-09-26 12:22:46.745 10805-10805 AndroidRuntime          com.example.grimoire                 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Here are **NoteDaoClass** :

```
package com.example.grimoire.data.dao;

import android.database.Cursor;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;

import com.example.grimoire.data.model.Note;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface NoteDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Note WHERE id = :id")
    Note getNote(Long id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Note ORDER BY id ASC")
    List<Note> getAllNote();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Note WHERE Id = :Id")
    Cursor getItemWithCursor(Long Id);

    @Insert
    void insertNote(Note note);


    @Query("DELETE FROM Note WHERE Id = :Id")
    int deleteItem(long Id);

    @Update
    void updateNote(Note note);
}
```

**GrimoireDatabase Class**:

```
package com.example.grimoire.data;

import static android.webkit.ConsoleMessage.MessageLevel.LOG;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;

import com.example.grimoire.data.model.AttachedFile;
import com.example.grimoire.data.model.Category;
import com.example.grimoire.data.model.Note;

import com.example.grimoire.data.dao.*;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

@Database(entities = {Note.class, Category.class, AttachedFile.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class GrimoireDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    // --- SINGLETON ---

    private static volatile GrimoireDatabase INSTANCE;

    // --- DAO ---

    public abstract NoteDao noteDao();

    public abstract CategoryDao categoryDao();

    public abstract AttachedFileDao attachedFileDao();
    private final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);


    // --- INSTANCE ---

    public static GrimoireDatabase getInstance(Context context) {

        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (GrimoireDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                                   GrimoireDatabase.class, "MyDatabase.db")
                            .addCallback(prepopulateDatabase())
                            .build();

                    Log.i("GrimoireDatabase","INstance builded");
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;

    }

    private static Callback prepopulateDatabase() {
        Log.i("GrimoireDatabase.Callback.prepopulateDatabase","before onCreate");
        return new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                Log.i("GrimoireDatabase.Callback.prepopulateDatabase.OnCreate","onCreate PAssed");
                super.onCreate(db);
                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {

                    Category cat = new Category(0, "Carnet Perso");
                    INSTANCE.categoryDao().insertCategory(cat);

                    Note note = new Note(cat.getIdCategory(), 0, "Moi", "Autun", "Sujet alpha", "sous-titre alpha", "exemple de note a", "10/9/2023", false, false);
                    INSTANCE.noteDao().insertNote(note);
                    note.setParameters(cat.getIdCategory(), 0, "Toi", "chambéry", "Sujet béta", "sous-titre béta", "exemple de note b", "05/10/2023", false, false);
                    INSTANCE.noteDao().insertNote(note);
                    Log.i("GrimoireDatabase.callback.prepolulate","note number : "+INSTANCE.noteDao().getAllNote().size()+"/n Category number : "+INSTANCE.categoryDao().getAllCategory().size());
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                super.onOpen(db);
            }

        };
    }
}
```

I have also tried Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() with the same result that nothing happens into this thread...

I am looking for solutions but not sure they are best practices :

How could I wait the background task from executor is done ? If I do what the purpose to have a asynchronous task if it is for waiting for it... Does someone can give me a good practice ?

Comment: `Executor#execute` does not necessarily run on another thread. That task may run on the calling method’s thread. Read the Javadoc.

Comment: When posting here, you'll generally get best results if you contrive a simplified example to demonstrate your issue.